# Reuse a View/ViewController for Text Entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextview, uitableview

I have a Table View Controller called "TripsTVC" that I would like to segue to a shared ViewController "NoteVC" that does nothing except collect text via a UITextView and send it back to the Table View Controller which will in turn save the data to an object through Core Data.  I have 5 rows that will all call the same `performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNote" sender:self`.  What's the easiest way for me to pass along which row is sending the request so that when I receive a response through delegation I can save the text that was received to my core data stack?

My only thoughts are to use the `reuseIdentifier` in the cell belonging to the row selected and pass that along to the NoteVC by defining a public variable in the NoteVC and then passing it back to the TripsTVC with a little if/else logic to handle it.  I just feel like there should be a better way.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an instance variable

```
@implementation TripsVC {
   NSIndexPath *_selectedIndexPath;
}
```

In your table delegate before calling the perform segue just set the _selectedIndexPath variable and you will then know which one to update

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  My brain feels much better now.  Thanks a million.